# Theorem reference: inscribed angle bisector

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

Given a circle $\omega$, let $O,A,B,K \in \omega$ (so that $OAKB$ is cyclic quadrilateral) and $\angle KOA = \angle KOB = \phi$.
I found that $OA + OB = 2 OK \cos \phi$. Is there a well-known theorem (something like power of point) which implies that?
I got the result using similarity and law of cosines (which is ugly).

Any other result on $OA + OB = (...)$ will be fine.

UPD:

I guess I need to clarify my motives at this point.
What I originally had in mind is the following. Given a bisector $OK$ of an angle $\angle AOB$ (with fixed points $A,B,K$) what is the condition for points $O,A,K,B$ to be concyclic? After some manipulation with complex numbers, I got the result I originally mentioned. So originally I hopped that power of point $O$ of some sort may appear (note that if $O$ was out of circle, concyclic condition is exactly the power of point theorem).

Comment: I check it using indeed law of cosines that isn't especialy ugly ! I don' think this result can rank as a "theorem", but I don't remember having seen it before.

Comment: @Andrey: How did you find the result?

Comment: @Narasimham triangles OAK and ALK are similar (L is intersection of diagonals), this gives us OA = AL * OK / AK. Same for the other side. Note that AK = BK. Now we have OA + OB = AB * OK / AK. From law of cosines for triangle AKB we get 2*AK*cos(phi) = AB.

Comment: @Andrey: Drop perpendiculars from $K$ to $A'$ and $B'$ on $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{OB}$; note that, because $\angle OAK$ and $\angle OBK$ are supplementary, one of $A'$ and $B'$ is non-exterior to the circle, and one is non-interior. So, we can write $$\begin{align}
|OA|\pm|AA'|=|OA'| &=|OK|\cos\phi \\
|OB|\mp|BB'|=|OB'| &=|OK|\cos\phi
\end{align}$$ But one readily shows $\triangle KAA'\cong\triangle KBB'$ so that $|AA'|=|BB'|$; thus, adding the equations gives the result.

Comment: @Blue that's nice. Not quite as fast as I thought, but close. Still, not an intuitive answer :(
What I was really looking into is some sort of generalization. E.g. what happens if OK is not a bisector? (Guess it doesn't provide an answer, but you get my point).

Comment: [Ptolemy's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem), perhaps.

Comment: Well, I just remembered [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4365446/947379) of mine, so as JeanMarie says, law of cosines is not that ugly.

Comment: @ACB was thinking of Ptolemy's theorem, but didn't quite found a use in this case. If you found one, please let me know!

Comment: A Ptolemaic rendition when $OK$ is not necessarily a bisector (but $\square OAKB$ is cyclic) might look something like this: Define $a:=|OA|$, $b:=|OB|$, $k:=|OK|$, $\alpha:=\angle KOA$, $\beta:=\angle KOB$, and let $d$ be the diameter of then circumcircle. Then by the Extended Law of Sines, $|AK|=d\sin\alpha$, $|BK|=d\sin\beta$, $|AB|=d\sin(\alpha+\beta)$, so that by Ptolemy, $$a\cdot d\sin\beta+b\cdot d\sin\alpha =k\cdot d\sin(\alpha+\beta)$$ Divide-through by $d$. (When $\alpha=\beta=\phi$, rewrite $\sin2\phi=2\sin\phi\cos\phi$, and divide-through by $\sin\phi$.)

Comment: @Blue yes! Great answer, I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ACB I finally found what I was looking for (just didn't see it quite well). Using Ptolemy's theorem and knowing that $AK = BK$ we get
$$
OA \cdot BK + OB \cdot AK = OK \cdot AB \Rightarrow OA + OB = \frac{AB}{AK} \cdot OK
$$
Now we can find that $\frac{AB}{AK} = 2 \cos \phi$ using similarity or other way around (e.g. complex numbers as I did it originally).

Thanks to everyone else as well!

UPD:

Check the @Blue comment to get a more generic approach:
$$
OA \sin \angle KOB + OB \sin \angle KOA = OK \sin \angle AOB
$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1894705)

Comment: @amWhy sorry, I'm new here. Didn't get what you mean. Ptolemy's theorem modification is the answer to theorem reference request. Blue's comment also provided a more general answer, which is good.

Answer (score 0):

An approximate construction as an aid to proof when the bisecting diagonal is not the diameter of the circle.

Angles subtended at center, circumference are $60^{0},30^{0}$

Central diagonal $OK$ length = $19.57; 19.57 \cos 30^{0}=16.95$

Average of equal angle enclosing arms $14.89,19.01 = 16.95$

For the proof we consider the polar equation of a circle passing through the origin. Angle subtended at rim is half that subtended at circle center.

$$OA= \rho_1= d \cos \alpha,~OK=\rho_2= d \cos (  \alpha+ \theta),~ OB=\rho_3= d \cos ( \alpha+ 2\theta); $$

Sum of two cosines trig formula

$$ \frac {\rho_1+\rho_3}{2} = d \cos(\alpha +\theta) \cos \theta  $$

$$ \rho_2 \cos \theta  = d \cos(\alpha +\theta) \cos \theta. $$

This is chord length expression rather than a theorem for an average/ middle polar angle argument.
$$ \frac {\rho_1+\rho_3}{2} = d \cos(\alpha +\theta) \cos \theta  $$

$$ \rho_2 \cos \theta  = d \cos(\alpha +\theta) \cos \theta. $$

Towards a generalization or theorem, not yet checked :

A property of the circle containing uniformly spaced pencil of chords (i.e., with uniform angular separation emanating from a point on the circumference) *may* be stated. If

$$ \bar{\rho}= \frac {\sum_{i=1
}^n \rho_i} {n}; ~ \bar{\theta}= \frac {\sum_{i=1
}^n \theta} {n}; $$

then

$$  \bar{\rho}=d \cos  \bar{\theta}\cos \theta. $$

[image]

Comment: How is this a hint? I need a theorem of some sort.

Comment: Consider B as origin in the *polar equation of circle* using angles w.r.t. vertical tangent at B. $ \rho = d \cos \alpha$. If $\theta $ is half angle these two calculate to the same quantity $ d \cos (\alpha+ \theta) \cos \theta).$ Can you fill in the details?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\angle OKA=x$, $\angle OKB=y$, $\angle OBK=B$, $\angle OAK=A$ and the radius of (circum)circle be $R$.

From extended law of sines, $OA=2R\sin x$, $OB=2R\sin y$ and $OK=2R\sin A$.

On the other hand, in $\triangle OKA$, since $A+\phi=180^{\circ}-x$ $$\sin x=\sin A\cos\phi+\cos A\sin\phi\tag1$$ and in $\triangle OKB$, $\sin y=\sin(B+\phi)=\sin B\cos\phi+\cos B\sin\phi$, and by using $\cos B=-\cos A$ and $\sin B=\sin A$, $$\sin y=\sin A\cos\phi-\cos A\sin\phi\tag2$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, $$\sin x +\sin y=2\cos\phi\sin A.\tag3$$
By multiplying $(3)$ by $2R$, we get $OA+OB=2OK\cos\phi.$