# Theorem reference: inscribed angle bisector part 2

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

So I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4605838/947379) not long ago.

With the same setup: $OL$ is bisector in triangle $OAB$, and $K = OL \cap \omega$, where
$\omega$ is circumcircle of $OAB$.
I got the following result:
$$
OA \cdot OB = OL \cdot OK.
$$
Is there a simple and clear proof (see my previous question)? Maybe some simple theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triangles $OAK$ and $OLB$ are similar because $\angle AOK\cong \angle LOB$ (bisector) while $\angle AKO\cong \angle LBO$ (both peripheral, subtended by the arc $AO$). Thus, the corresponding sides are proportional: $OA:OK=OL:OB$, i.e. $OA\cdot OB=OK\cdot OL$.